# Python Terminal Invalid Syntax

Tags: python

I am new to python and have a problem running a saved python file from IDLE in terminal. It throws an error when running. I changed directories to the proper place (Desktop) then typed `python helloworld.py` then it gives me this error. Why would it do this when it runs in IDLE fine?

```
>>> print ("Hello World!")
Hello World!
```

```
File "helloworld.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste the text directly from the interactive window in IDLE which happens to contain the Python version information at the top? If so - remove that and anything else that isn't code...

Comment: Welcome to python! I suggest you paste the contents in the file `helloworld.py`.

Comment: I have updated with the code from helloworld.py. Is it something to do with the Tcl/Tk issue?

Answer (score 0):

your file should only have the following code in it:

```
print ("Hello World!")
```

all the rest is just part of the IDLE's interface.

Comment: Hmm...still get the same error even with the deleted code

Comment: @user2371862 you cant get get a syntax error for code that's not in the file

Comment: Is it possible it has to do with a Tcl/Tk version inconsistency? It says that version Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) may be unstable. It still gives me the same syntax error, but I don't understand why when I all have is "print ("Hello World!").

Comment: 1. if your current file has what the post now says it does, then you still have some leftovers in it. you should have no angle brackets ('>') and no response from the REPL, just your command.
2. sorry if this is obvious, but are you sure you're running the latest version of your script, after editing it?

Comment: It was the '>>>' brackets that were throwing the error. How stupid of me, thanks for helping!